# How to define a new function ('operator') in MathJax?

Tags: mathjax

I am using MathJax to display formulae on my web sites. Out of the box, MathJax recognises many functions like `sin`, `cos`, ..., but many are missing, such as `sech` (hyperbolic secant) and `csch`(hyperbolic cosecant). I know I can still use these functions in formulae by means of `\text`, such as

```
\text{sech} u
```

However, I would rather make `\sech` work. To this end, I tried

```
<div style="display:none">
  $\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}$
</div>
```

right after `<body>`. (I also tried to add an asterisk after `DeclareMathOperator`.)

This *almost* works. The problem is that now

```
\sech^2 u
```

places the square *above* `sech`, instead of after it ([proof](http://english.rejbrand.se/trecs/pseudosphere.asp)). Is there a way to fix this? What is the prefered way to define new functions ('operators') in MathJax? Surely there is a good way, for who can live without a full spectrum of hyperbolic functions?!

Comment: I'm not sure if MathJax corresponds 100% to latex, but could you try `\sech\nolimits^{2}`?

Comment: @phg: Thank you for your comment. Yes, that does work, but it kind of removes the benefit of making `\sech` work in the first place. Indeed, even `\text{sech}^2` takes less characters to type than `\sech\nolimits^2`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `\DeclareMathOperator` macro does not provide a means of declaring an operator that always has limits in the super- and subscript positions, which is why your `\sech` get the superscript placed above it when used in displayed equations.

What you want is the following:

```
<div style="display:none">
  $
    \newcommand{\sech}{\mathop{\rm sech}\nolimits}
    \newcommand{\csch}{\mathop{\rm csch}\nolimits}
  $
</div>
```

This will get you operators that work like `\sin` and `\cos`.  Note that the spacing will be better with this form than with your versions using `\text{...}`, since `\mathop` will provide the proper spacing around the operator name (however there is a bug in MathJax that causes the space to be lost when there is a super- or subscript; this will be fixed in the next release).

Comment: Just put this in a macro according to the [MathJaX documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros) and it worked perfectly! I added `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hun.Config({Tex: {Macros: {erf: "\\mathop{\\rm erf}\\nolimits"}}})<script>` to my `layout.html` template in my `_tempates` folder, after making sure it the templates path was specified in my `conf.py` file.